# What is a distribution-wise asymmetric measure?

Tags: statistics, probability, distribution, mathematics

I was trying to understand KL-Divergence, $$D_{KL} \langle P(X) \Vert P(Y) \rangle,$$ and was going through its Wikipedia article. It says the following

> In contrast to variation of information, it is a distribution-wise asymmetric measure and thus does not qualify as a statistical metric of spread - it also does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

What is the meaning of distribution-wise asymmetric measure? Is there a symmetric measure? What are the rules that a quantity should follow to be qualified as a statistical metric of spread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of distribution-wise asymmetric measure?

The **(forward) KL-divergence** is distribution-wise asymmetric because if you calculate it as $$D_{KL} \langle P(X) \Vert P(Y) \rangle$$ where $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ are two different probability distributions with the latter being the reference distribution, then $$D_{KL} \langle P(Y)\Vert P(X)\rangle \neq D_{KL}\langle P(X)\Vert P(Y)\rangle.$$ In other words, the **reverse KL-divergence** is not equal to the forward KLD. If forward KLD *were* symmetric, then the above would be an equality, not an inequality.

> Is there a symmetric measure?

A distribution-wise *symmetric* measure would, for example, be **mutual information**:

$$I(X;Y) = H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y) = D_{KL} \langle P(X,Y) || P(X) \cdot P(Y) \rangle,$$
where $H(X)$ is the entropy of a variable $X$'s probability distribution, since $I(Y;X) = I(X;Y)$. Mutual information is a special case of the KLD in which the joint distribution is measured against the product of marginal distributions.

> What are the rules that a quantity should follow to be qualified as a statistical metric of spread?

The [three axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition) that a distance metric should meet are:

1. Identity of indiscernibles
2. Symmetry
3. Sub-additivity or triangle inequality

Since mutual information does not obey the triangle of inequality, it does not fit the full criteria for being a distance metric. Instead, **variation of information** *does* meet all of the above requirements and *is* a true metric:

$$VI(X;Y) = H(X,Y) - I(X;Y)$$
where $H(X,Y)$ is the joint entropy.

Comment: what are those double pipes between P(X) and P(Y)? What do i call them?